# How to merge two lists into a new list sequantially?

Tags: python, list

I'm working with lists in `Python 3.x`.

I want to merge two lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [7, 8, 9, 19]
```

Expected output like this:

```
list3 = [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 19]
```

**I am not allowed to use any advanced data structures and need to write in a pythonic way.**

Comment: `zip(list1, list2)`

Comment: @rdas That would give a zip object, but even if you cast it to a list, you'd get `[(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 19)]`, which is not flattened as asked

Comment: @ChatterOne that was a hint - since this sounds like a homework problem.

Answer (score 4):

Simply we can use `list comprehension` like this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [7, 8, 9, 19]

list3 = [v for v1_v2 in zip(list1, list2) for v in v1_v2]

assert list3 == [1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 19]
```

Comment: If this answers your question perfectly, then feel free to mark it as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*zip(v1, v2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

[`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together then flatten with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = [7,8,9,19]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `reduce`  from `functools` over a sum of the two lists using `zip`

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add

list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [7,8,9,19]

x = list(reduce(add, zip(list1, list2)))
x
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 19]
```

Comment: In this approach creates a lot of intermediate list objects (in reduce function).

Comment: Don't use repeated adds to concatenate lists. This is bad performance wise.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll look into the computation performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [7, 8, 9, 19]

new_list = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    new_list.extend([list1[i], list2[i]])
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9, 4, 19]
```